# Incorrect zeros positions in zplane

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to plot pole/zero plot of a simple polynomial (1+z)^(2p) for p=7. My code is as follows:

```
p = 7;
rCoeffs = [1 1];
for ii=1:2*p-1
    rCoeffs = conv(rCoeffs, [1 1]);
end
zplane(real(rCoeffs),1);
```

The plot displays the following:

[image]

I don't understand why the zeros are complex numbers. I think that all the zeros should be located at z=-1 but this plot shows a circle. This doesn't happen when p is small but again I have seen a few plots online that are apparently generated by zplane and they show large number of zeros on a particular point.

Comment: @NathanG I am sorry I couldn't get your comment. Don't you think it is doing the same, i.e., convolution is actually polynomial multiplication/expansion?

Comment: You're right.  I think it has something to do with the number of permutations MATLAB takes to solve large polynomials before it escapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you're looking for 14 solutions to the equation given the setup. Unfortunately the general solution to polynomial equations of order 5 or greater doesn't exist and must be found numerically. The solution provided is correct only in that is approximately what the algorithm thinks you're looking for.

I would add that Nathan's method works as intended, and if you change it slightly, you will see all the solutions to the above equation.

```
z = tf('z',1)
H = (1+z)^(2*7);
[p,z1] = pzmap(H)
z1 % solution to H = 0
(1+z1)^(2*7)
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way:

```
p = 7

z = zpk('z',0.1);
H = (1+z)^(2*p);

pzmap(H)
```

Comment: I actually have a polynomial's coefficients in a vector that I want to multiply with (1+z)^2p (say in h1) and then create a pole/zero plot. I am not sure how I will be able to do this with the method you suggested. In your method, I think we should know pole and zeros before drawing the pole/zero plot ?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Just enter your z equation into H and pzmap will plot it for you.